# Creating a 2d array of vectors, traversal

Tags: c++

I have a list of vectors. Each vector contains n numbers. I want to have k x k such vectors. To initialize it, would I do

```
vector<int> v1[k][k];
for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)//initialize each vector with n numbers
  for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    for(int c = 0; c < n; c++)
      v1[j][i].push_back(n);
//deletion if number already exists, confused about this part.
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)//iteration of the array of vectors
  for(int j = 0; j < k; j++ )
   for(int u = 0; u < v1[i][j].size();u++)//iteration of each element(n) in vector
     if(v1[i][j][u] == existing_number)
        v1[i][j].erase(v1[i][j].begin + ( i* k + j))
```

Am I accessing and erasing the elements correctly? I'm not sure how to accessing the element in the array of vectors.

Comment: Did I do it correctly? I'm not sure if I'm accessing the element correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want vector of vectors (of vectors)?
A vector of vectors is declared e.g. with k equal to 9 as:

```
unsigned long k = 9;
vector< vector<int> > vec(k,vector<int>(k));
```

Comment: not really vector of vectors because the k x k is constant and never changing, which is why i used it as an array. However, the list of n numbers are dynamic, which is why i used a vector.